# How to combine multiple fviz_dist plots into one plot

Tags: r

I have unsuccessfully tried to combine multiple `fviz_dist` (`factoextra` package) plots into one plot using `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` and by naming the plots and adding them e.g., PlotA + PlotB (as I have seen with histograms).

looking forward to hearing your tips and tricks

```
#Generates 4 individual plots
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
fviz_dist(dist.euclraw)
fviz_dist(dist.euclscaled)
fviz_dist(dist.corraw)
fviz_dist(dist.corscaled)
```

Comment: The output from `fviz_dist` is a `ggplot2` which cannot be arranged using `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do it like

```
library(factoextra)
library(ggpubr)
library(gridExtra)

data(USArrests)
dist.pearson <- get_dist(USArrests, stand = TRUE, method = "pearson")
dist.euclraw <- get_dist(USArrests, stand = TRUE, method = "euclidean")

p1 <- fviz_dist(dist.pearson)
p2 <- fviz_dist(dist.euclraw)
ggpubr::ggarrange(p1,p2)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Made a plot with four fviz_dist plots. Greatly appreciated Babba Das.